# Picking a specific line with a specific string

Tags: perl

I am trying this in Perl to pick one complete line from whole document which contains "CURRENT_RUN_ID". I have been using below code to accomplish the above said task but I am unable to enter the while loop.

```
my $sSuccessString = "CURRENT_RUN_ID";

open(LOG, "$slogfile") or die("Can't open $slogfile\n");
my $sLines;
{
    local $/ = undef;
    $sLines=<LOG>;
}
my $spool = 0;
my @matchingLines;

while (<LOG>) 
{
    print OUTLOG "in while loop\n";

    if (m/$sSuccessString/i) {
        print OUTLOG "in if loop\n";
        $spool = 1;
        print map { "$_ \n" } @matchingLines;
        @matchingLines = ();
    }
    if ($spool) {
        push (@matchingLines, $_);
    }
}
```

Comment: When I see a variable called `$sSuccessString`, all I can muster is "***nooooooooo!!!***" In fact, you are violating the spirit of Hungarian notation. Everything in Perl can be stringified ... so you don't need two reminders that the variable is a string with the `s` prefix and the `String` suffix. Instead, `my $success_re = qr/CURRENT_RUN_ID/i;` or `my $log_fname = ...` would actually be in keeping with the ***spirit*** of Hungarian notation.

Answer (score 4):

You are already done reading from the filehandle `LOG` after you have slurped it into `$sLines`. `<LOG>` in the head of the `while` will return `undef` because it has reached `eof`. You either have to use that variable `$sLines` in your `while` loop or get rid of it. You're not using it anyway.

If you only want to print the line that matches, all you need to do is this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh_in, '<', 'input_file' or die $!;
open my $fh_out '>', 'output_file' or die $!;

while (my $line = <$fh_in>) {
  print $fh_out $line if $line =~ m/CURRENT_RUN_ID/;
}

close $fh_in;
close $fh_out;
```

Comment: Hi simbabque, I tried implementing your code, keeping "$slogfile" as input file and a new name for output_file but getting (bareword "output_file" not allowed while strict subs) error. please suggest

Comment: @Sur that's a syntax error. You probably forgot either a `$` on a variable name or to quote the filename. Just read the line that the message points to. It will be rather obvious. ;)

Answer (score 1):

When you execute this code:

```
$sLines=<LOG>;
```

it reads all of the data from `LOG` into `$sLines` and it leaves the file pointer for `LOG` at the end of the file. So when you next try to read from that file handle with:

```
while (<LOG>)
```

nothing is returned as there is no more data to read.

If you want to read the file twice, then you will need to use the `seek()` function to reset the file pointer before your second read.

```
seek LOG, 0, 0;
```

But, given that you never do anything with `$sLines` I suspect that you can probably just remove that whole section of the code.

The whole thing with `$spool` and `@matchingLines` seems strange too. What were you trying to achieve there?

I think your code can be simplified to just:

```
my $sSuccessString = "CURRENT_RUN_ID";

open(LOG, $slogfile) or die("Can't open $slogfile\n");

while (<LOG>) {
    print OUTLOG if /$sSuccessString/i/;
}
```

Personally, I'd make it even simpler, by reading from STDIN and writing to STDOUT.

```
my $sSuccessString = 'CURRENT_RUN_ID';

while (<>) {
    print if /$sSuccessString/i/;
}
```

And then using Unix I/O redirection to connect up the correct files.

```
$ ./this_filter.pl < your_input.log > your_output.log
```